# Какие проблемы присутствуют в данном коде и как его улучшить?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, стек

```
public class Stack {
private final Object[] buf;
private int position;

public Stack(int size) {
    buf = new Object[size];
}

public void push(Object o) {
    if(position > buf.length - 1)
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    buf[position++] = o;
}

public Object pop() {
    if(position <= 0)
        return null;
    return buf[--position];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (position == 0);
}

public boolean equals(Stack stack) {
    return buf == stack.buf;
}
```

}

Comment: В этом вам поможет данный ресурс этой сети: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: можете пояснить назначение и содержимое вот этого метода `equals` ?

Comment: Да, он сравнивает лишь то, обладают ли они одинаковыми ссылками .

Comment: OutOfMemoryError - выбрасывать ошибки не есть хорошо, ьетод equals и hashcode должны переопределяться вместе, equals переопределен странно, вам действительно нужен массив Object?

Comment: @Miron про назначение - я имел ввиду не что делает метод, а зачем он вообще нужен - для чего автору надо срвнивать два стека? И если автор сравнивает только ссылки на массивы - то это тоже не имеет смысла, так как исходя из имплементации, два разных стека не могут ссылаться на один и тот же массив, разные стеки - всегда разные массивы, то есть тогда достаточно сравнить ссылки на стеки. Если же автору надо сравнивать и содержимое массивов (зачем то), то непонятно зачем это делать и какие критерии эквивлентности он хочет использовать.

Comment: Я с вами согласился и написал для автора описание действия его equals

Comment: Еще рекомендую уменьшать счетчик ссылок для выталкиваемых объектов

Comment: @Miron, code review - онтопик.

Answer (score 0):

1-ое предложение:
Пишите isEmpty() в методе pop, так эта переменная мимо нуля проскочить не может.
2-ое предложение:
Если вам нужен стак с одинаковыми по типу элементами, вам стоит воспользоваться дженериками.

И у вас одна серьезная проблема:
Метод equals написан неправильно. Он сравнивает лишь ссылки на объекты. А вам нужно сравнить их содержимое. Правильное решение(если я правильно понял посыл):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object stack) {
    if(!(stack instanceof Stack)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(stack == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(((Stack)stack).buf.length != buf.length || ((Stack)stack).position != position) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        if(!((Stack)stack).buf[i].equals(buf)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

И добавьте hashcode, как это советуют сделать люди из комментариев

Comment: Логично, кстати

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение отмечу еще:

1. Хорошо бы классу как то наследоваться от какого-либо класса из Java Collections, иначе странно, что класс `Stack` болтается сам по себе.
2. Про `equals()` уже и написали и прокомментировали - поддержу
3. Не хватает метода `peek()` - взять значение на вершине стека без выталкивания
4. При переполнении стека надо выбрасывать исключение `IndexOutOfBoundException` или же тупо терять значение на дне стека сдвигая все значения ко дну
5. Надо сделать из него Generics типа `Stack<T>` - код принципиально не изменится, зато станет приятнее

Comment: ну и классическое, чистить ячейку массива во время pop операции, иначе можно утечку памяти получить :)